# Vim Visual Mode preserve syntax highlight of selected text

Tags: vim, terminal, syntax-highlighting

How do I preserve language-specific syntax highlighting in `vim` visual mode? I would like to change **only the background** and preserve the text original color when selecting text for editing (e.g. copy/paste). I also would like to do this in `vim diff` color scheme.

I have played with `highlight Visual` command but it always ends up overwriting the text syntax highlighting.

I am using `vim` version 8.1 (2018 May 18) and [Amix](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) `.vimrc`. His configuration setup contains a `my_configs.vim` file in which I am trying to add my modifications (e.g., `hi Visual`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is:

`hi! Visual cterm=none ctermfg=none ctermbg=242`

It was pretty foolish of my part, but **I was missing** the `ctermfg=none` part to overwrite (I believe) any configuration set by Amix `vim` setup. For his setup, if you don't set this property the text color will change in visual mode. I believe you could use `gui`, `guibg` and `guifg` analogously.

Answer (score 3):

give this a try:

```
hi! Visual term=reverse ctermbg=242 guibg=DarkGrey
```

An advice: do NOT use any "vim distributions" or "Ultimate vimrcs"

Comment: Thanks, Kent, but that doesn't work for this setup (maybe some other command has priority over mine - idk). Also, thanks for the advice. I do not intend on using it forever, just to "see some examples of setup".